# Find an element in a list with tuple in Python

Tags: python, tuples

I have a little complicated data and want to find specific element with *key* tuple. *target* tuple is a little different from *key*, because it has an *id* property. So I cannot use ***key in target***.

So what's the best way to implement smart searching in this case?

```
targets = [
    {"id": 0, "X": (), "Y": (), "Z": () },
    {"id": 1, "X": (1,), "Y": (5,), "Z": ()},
    {"id": 2, "X": (1,), "Y": (5, 7), "Z": ()},
    {"id": 3, "X": (2,), "Y": (5, 7), "Z": (1,)},
    {"id": 4, "X": (1, 2), "Y": (5, 7), "Z": (1,)},
    {"id": 5, "X": (1, 2), "Y": (5, 7), "Z": (1,3)},
]

key = {"X": (1,), "Y": (5, 7), "Z": ()}
```

I want to implement *find* method to extract expected slot like below.

```
In []: find(targets, key)
Out[]: {'id': 2, 'X': (1,), 'Y': (5, 7), 'Z': ()}
```

Comment: `(1)` is not a tuple; that's just a single integer. The `()` only groups there, you need a *comma* to produce a tuple: `(1,)`.

Comment: There are lots of brute-force ways to do this. What have you tried?

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? This is no different from other 'search for a value in a dictionary* questions, really. The solution is to brute-force (search every value in every dictionary), or build an index you re-use and maintain that maps the other direction.

Comment: If your data is not very large why don't you just brute force it? If the data is very huge you ll have to restructure it anyways...

Comment: `[target for target in targets if all(item in target.items() for item in key.items())]`

Comment: @PeterWood: `target.items() < key.items()` on Python 3, `target.viewitems() < key.viewitems()` on Python 2. As long as the values are hashable that is (which is the case here).

Comment: @MartijnPieters I am always learning things from you. I'm so glad to answer and then get it improved.

Answer (score 2):

If the key-value pairs must match exactly, you can use [*Dictionary view objects*](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) to treat the key-value pairs as *sets*. You want to find a [*strict subset*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set.issubset):

```
def find(targets, key):
    for target in targets:
        if key.items() < target.items():
            return target
```

This finds the *first* match only.

You could turn this into a one-liner:

```
next((target for target in targets if key.items() < target.items()), None)
```

If you must produce **all** matches, you can replace `return` with `yield` in the above method to turn it into a generator, or you could use a list comprehension:

```
[target for target in targets if key.items() < target.items()]
```

The above uses Python 3 syntax. In Python 2, dictionary views are available through the special `.viewkeys()`, `.viewvalues()` and `.viewitems()` methods, so add in `view` to the method name:

```
def find(targets, key):
    # Python 2 version
    for target in targets:
        if key.viewitems() < target.viewitems():
            return target
```

Demo (on Python 3):

```
>>> targets = [
...     {"id": 0, "X": (), "Y": (), "Z": () },
...     {"id": 1, "X": (1,), "Y": (5,), "Z": ()},
...     {"id": 2, "X": (1,), "Y": (5, 7), "Z": ()},
...     {"id": 3, "X": (2,), "Y": (5, 7), "Z": (1,)},
...     {"id": 4, "X": (1, 2), "Y": (5, 7), "Z": (1,)},
...     {"id": 5, "X": (1, 2), "Y": (5, 7), "Z": (1,3)},
... ]
>>> key = {"X": (1,), "Y": (5, 7), "Z": ()}
>>> def find(targets, key):
...     for target in targets:
...         if key.items() < target.items():
...             return target
...
>>> find(targets, key)
{'Y': (5, 7), 'X': (1,), 'Z': (), 'id': 2}
>>> next((target for target in targets if key.items() < target.items()), None)
{'Y': (5, 7), 'X': (1,), 'Z': (), 'id': 2}
>>> [target for target in targets if key.items() < target.items()]
[{'Y': (5, 7), 'X': (1,), 'Z': (), 'id': 2}]
```

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I could confirm your code. But find(targets, {"X": (1,), "Y": (7, 5), "Z": ()}) is not working because of "Y"'s values order is different from one. Are there any way to ignore the order?

Comment: @jef: yes, the `'Y'` tuple has a different order. Order *matters* in tuples. If you must ignore order, store `set` or `frozenset` objects instead of tuples.

Comment: @jef: if you **must** support tuples and these **must** be matched in any order, you'd have to convert the key to using sets first, then test for each target with the values converted to sets:  `key = {k: set(v) for k, v in key.items()}` at the top of the function, then `if key.items() <= set((k, set(v) for k, v in target.items() if isinstance(v, tuple)):` in the loop (replacing the current `if` test). This is a lot more costly.